# Breaking in new retzu'ot*

Tags: tefilin, how-to

I got new retzu'ot this Sunday from a [fellow user of this forum, a sofer and my chevrutah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/679/yitzchak). However, these new retzu'ot† are much harder than my old ones were when I got them. How would one go about breaking them in, keeping in mind that they do have kedushat tefillin and, as such, should not be treated in a disrespectful manner ?

---

*This is not an halachic question and, as such, CYLOR does not apply.

†When I say "hard" I mean that they are stiffer and less supple.

Comment: Did you ask your sofer/chavrusa?

Comment: Like all leather, oil helps make it supple. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oiling_%28leather_processing%29  For most people that could be years of sweat.

Comment: There is still a Halakhic question of if a method proposed is Halakhically acceptable.

Comment: @sam, I did, he didn't have any ides

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'm aware. I can always ask him, since kabbalah in safrut gives someone heter lehora'ah for sta"m matters.

Comment: Most leather objects- shoes, jackets, bags-are best broken in by using them. I don't see how these new straps (which sound like they're very well made) wouldn't be the same. As an added bonus, halachically speaking, while I'm no posek, "using your tefillin 6 mornings a week" is definitely a halachically acceptable way to break them in.

Comment: @JoshK, I wear them six mornings a week. I want to accelerate the break-in process so I can focus more on my tefillah and less on uncomfortable retzu’ot

Comment: Perhaps my answer was a bit flippant, @NoachMiFrankfurt, I'm sorry. If you wrap tighter than you usually would it will accelerate the process but of course it will be even more uncomfortable